# Stop loading the page causes no other link clickable

Tags: android, react-native, webview

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, WebView} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this._webview = null;

    }

    _onNavigationStateChange(webViewState){
        console.log(webViewState.url);
        var no=Math.random();
        console.log(no);
        if (no>0.5){
            console.log("found");
            this._webview.stopLoading();
        }
        return true;
    }

  render(){
    return (
        <WebView
            ref={component => this._webview = component}
            source={{uri: 'https://www.google.com/search?ei=DI9ZXMTAMtb-rQGFwaDYDw&q=web+development+company+in+delhi&oq=web+development+company+in+delhi&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0j0i7i30l4j0i5i30l4.32946.34428..34777...0.0..0.220.1407.0j8j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i304i39j0i13j0i7i5i30.WD85QRQKyog'}}
            onNavigationStateChange={
                this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)
            }
            javaScriptEnabled = {true}
            domStorageEnabled = {true}
            startInLoadingState={false}
        />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Once I stop loading using webview.stoploading it doesn't allow any other link to be opened the no link is active again. 
In my case it open google link and when I select one link and no>0.5 then I stop loads the page that was about to open but thereafter I can't open any other link

Comment: first, you should use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview   and you can try to replace ` this._webview.stopLoading()` for ` this._webview.back()` (or something like this)

Comment: .back()  ? but why?

Comment: I am just thinking if you stop it in middle of fetching new page it have not old data for rendering old page and also have not a data for rendering new page it is just stack between